# Mod Rewrite Slash Problem

Tags: php, regex, mod-rewrite

I searched this problem in the site, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a php page, call
http://www.domain.com/topic.php?name=xyz

I want to call this page with
http://www.domain.com/topic/xyz

What I tried is;

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]*)$ /topic.php?name=$1 [L]

However because of this "/" I get 404 error. If I try "-" instead of "/" it works. I guess "/" forward user to folder "/topic" so I need a solution to fix it.

Comment: First one in the code. While I'm calling ...com/topic/xyz it directs to "topic" folder and return a 404.

Comment: Your rule works just fine for me. Does the file `topic.php` actually exist in the root folder? Is the `.htaccess` located in the root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my solution to problem. It is a bit late though :)

I edit my .htaccess such that

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* redirect.php [L]
```

I create a redirect.php as you see. In this file, I explode slashes, then by using if statement I set

```
$path =  explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
switch ($path[1])
{
    case 'topic': $_GET[name]=$path[2]; include('topic.php'); break;
}
```

As you see setting $_GET as a code isn't handsome, but it works like a charm! :) Thanks all for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work given the fact that your topic name follows the pattern `([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)` - and if it doesn't match it, it probably should(and it's your job to sanitize it so that it matches), because it's a URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+).html$ topic.php?name=$1 [L]
```

**NOTE:**

In your request you say you want the url to look like this: `http://www.domain.com/topic/xyz` and in the .htaccess rule you tried to write it with `.html` at the end. If you don't want `.html` at the end you should do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^topic/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ topic.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I try, but I'm still getting the same error. I am thinking if it is related to "AllowEncodedSlashes on" command.

Comment: There is no significant difference between `[a-zA-Z0-9-_]` and `[^/]` in this case. You missed `*` (or `+`) quantifier also.

Comment: @zerkms I just saw that I missed the `+` so it would be matching only one char. Note to self: don't answer on SO when sleepy :)

Answer (score 0):

Too bored to guess anymore.

My .htaccess (taken from your question):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^topic/([^/]*)$ /topic.php?name=$1 [L]
```

My topic.php:

```
<?php

var_dump($_GET);
```

Request:

```
http://localhost/topic/xyz
```

Result:

```
array(1) { ["name"]=> string(3) "xyz" }
```

So it just works on `Apache 2.2.14`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to espace the forward slash, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^topic\/([^\/]*)$ topic.php?name=$1 [L]
```

And in Bogdan's solution you're missing a + after the character class, now it only matches one character :P

Comment: Still getting 404.
The problem is not related with / in the paranthesis, it is first one.

Comment: Why need he? `/` haven't any special meaning in mod_rewrite.

Comment: Because if I fix the code as

"RewriteRule ^topic-([^\/]*)$ /topic.php?name=$1 [L]"

Then www.domain.com/topic-xyz works.

Comment: Does it work if you escape the other forward slash as well? (updated my post).

Comment: `/` isn't being used as a delimiter here, so you do not have to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the line `AddHandler type-map var` in your `httpd.conf`, try commenting it out.

It might seem odd, but this functionality (which is not often used, but is enabled in the default `httpd.conf` for the Apache "It Worked!" page) has caused me grief along similar lines in the past.

It's something to do with the fact that you have a file "topic.php", and Apache allows you to call it like "topic/en-us". Or *something like that*. You'd have to [look up the feature in the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html) to get the specifics; I'm just going off memory.

Comment: I'm using GoDaddy. So no hope for me, maybe I should accept the fact that I can't use / in my URLs.

Comment: Thanks for warning :) I will try to escape soon.

Comment: @Kenshi: You get a +1 for that